# View a list of actual running queries

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

On my test server there is a large query that is running (which is okay), but it is a multi-line query. E.g. in SSMS I told it to run something like:

```
begin transaction;
query;
query;
query;
query;
commit;
```

I want to see which query within the list is executing. Selecting `text` from `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` returns the entire statement, not the particular command that is executing within the list. Is there a way to view the individual commands that are being processed?

In case it matters (sometimes it does), this is running on a SQL Azure instance.

Comment: In the performance view in the Azure portal I can click on a query ID (number) and see the individual line for a query that took a long time, though that isn't necessarily the one that is currently executing.

Comment: It is a transaction - the entire query IS running, technically, even if it is broken up into multiple individual pieces. If you want to know which one is actually running, logging the start of each piece of the transaction (similar to how SSIS logs each step) will give you that information, but only after the fact - since the logging will be within the transaction as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use `DBCC INPUTBUFFER`

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(your session id)
```

It will display the query that is executing in your session

Comment: That gives me EventType "Language Event", Parameters "0", EventInfo "<the entire list of queries>".

Comment: @Josh - yeah checked it.. It is showing the entire batch

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find my complete set o queries useful to show transactions running, time-wait events and open transactions with plan and sql texts:
http://zaboilab.com/sql-server-toolbox/queries-to-see-rapidly-what-your-sql-server-is-doing-now

Comment: careful on self promotion on this site

Comment: Unfortunately the queries in this also showed me the whole batch text.